# Sort each column of R data.table

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I am trying to sort the columns of a data.table independently of the row structure. I can do it with sapply and sort, but I feel like I'm not doing it right- it seems pretty slow, and the fact that I need to use as.data.table suggests that I'm not doing the assignments by-reference, which is what I want. Is there a better way to do it? Here is my code:

```
r <- 10000
c <- 5000

dt <- as.data.table(replicate(c, rnorm(r)))

dt <- as.data.table(sapply(dt,sort))
```

Comment: `apply(as.matrix(dt),2, sort)` is slower... which I would think is natural to benchmark against.

Comment: Please see my updated post. I think my benchmarking was not done right originally. On the second iterations the columns are already sorted for some cases. We get more realistic comparison by using `times = 1`.

Comment: Got it- thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems using a for loop with `set()` is faster (better?) here is a benchmark:

*Edit*: Added Frank's suggestion and it seems to beat anything we've tried so far:

*Edit 2*: Changed `times = 1` for fairer comparison - the original solution seems pretty good now.

*Edit 3*: Added Hugh's suggestion and it seems to be an improvement:

```
dt <- as.data.table(replicate(c, rnorm(r)))
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)
dt4 <- copy(dt)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  set = {for (col in names(dt)) {set(dt, j = col, value = sort(dt[[col]]))}},
  original = as.data.table(sapply(dt2,sort)),
  matrixapply = apply(as.matrix(dt2), 2, sort),
  frank = dt3[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, sort)],
  hugh = for (j in seq_along(dt4)) { v <- .subset2(dt4, j); set(dt4, j = j, value = v[order(v)]) },
  times = 1
)
```

#### Results

```
Unit: seconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
         set 6.223533 6.223533 6.223533 6.223533 6.223533 6.223533     1
    original 5.598481 5.598481 5.598481 5.598481 5.598481 5.598481     1
 matrixapply 6.039590 6.039590 6.039590 6.039590 6.039590 6.039590     1
       frank 5.255841 5.255841 5.255841 5.255841 5.255841 5.255841     1
        hugh 5.084420 5.084420 5.084420 5.084420 5.084420 5.084420     1
```

Comment: Try `for (j in seq_along(DT)) {
    v <- .subset2(DT, j)
    set(DT, j = j, value = v[order(v)])
  }
  DT`